# VAR estimate input name-value pair

Tags: matlab, var

When the estimate function is used to train the VAR model, the covariance matrix of the original data is not positive definite, so I should get a positive definite matrix after using the data prediction. How should I put it into the estimate?

I try to use this form

model = varm(64, 2);

model = estimate(model, data, 'CovarianceMatrix', Sigma_psd)

But the error 'CovarianceMatrix' is an unrecognized parameter. See the documentation for this function for a list of valid name-value pairs.